# iOS Text Field (JVFloatLabeledTextField) causing odd keyboard behavior

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I have a login page on my app that exhibits weird behavior on the iPads but works well on the iPhones. On the iPad username/password fields pop-up the keyboard but as soon as the user types it pushed the keyboard down (see attached image). The text fields are JVFloatLabeledTextField which are UITextField subclasses.

I'm at a loss on where to start short of redoing the whole screen. Any thoughts are appreciated.
[image: collapsed keyboard]

Comment: "On the iPad username/password fields pop-up the keyboard but as soon as the user types it pushed the keyboard down (see attached image).", can't you post a screenshot of your whole screen? I can't imagine the "pushed the keyboard down" part.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add another image. See if these links work. Here's the start screen https://i.imgur.com/OfhcYt3.png. Here's what is looks like after you pop the keyboard and type a single character. https://i.imgur.com/NO0rVHC.png